# How to set WooCommerce notices from functions,php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, notifications

I'm processing some requests in my Wordpress theme's `functions.php`, and need to set notices there.

But none of the WooCommerce methods are available. How can I access `wc_add_notice()` from there?

Code from my `functions.php` file:

```
function my_function() {
    // some code
    wc_add_notice('Yay!', 'success');
    wp_redirect( '/' );
    die();
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_action', 'my_function' );
add_action( 'admin_post_action', 'my_function' );
```

**NOTE:** There is a similar question [Display Woocommerce notices on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631939/display-woocommerce-notices-on-a-page), but this question is not a duplicate of that one. The notices will be displayed on standard WooCommerce template files. I'm attempting to *set* notices from within the `functions.php` file.

Comment: How are they not available, what is the actual error? Are you just unable to call them because there doesn't appear to be such a  function in the scope?

Comment: @kaanay03, updated with code example

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://njengah.com/create-woocommerce-admin-notice/).

Answer (score 0):

WC Notices will only show on WooCommerce template pages it won't show on your main home page unless it's a WooCommerce page. They are shown when the function `wc_print_notices()` is called.

Comment: Yes. The notices I'm trying to set will definitely be displayed on a WooCommerce page.