# Custom register page not outputting any error messages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-accounts

I created a custom register page in my own plugin by copying the template from WooCommerce (my_account).
Everything works fine, but I can't output error messages when the customer registers, e.g. when a field is not filled.

I tried it with billing_first_name and billing_last_name, but I am getting nothing (only reload of the page). At least, no customer is created, so the validation works. On the my_account-Page from WooCommerce, error messages are outputted.

Here is my plugin code:

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'b2b_login_register' );
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'bbloomer_validate_woo_account_registration_fields', 10, 3 );
  
function bbloomer_validate_woo_account_registration_fields( $errors, $username, $email ) {  
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.' );
    }
    return $errors;
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'bbloomer_save_woo_account_registration_fields', 1 );
  
function bbloomer_save_woo_account_registration_fields( $customer_id ) {
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['company'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_company', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['company'] ));
    }
}

function b2b_login_register()   {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )  {
        $my_account_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
            header("Location:" . $my_account_url );
            exit();
       }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php 
    // HERE I ADDED THE NOTICE - IT ONLY WORKS AT THIS PLACE AND IN THIS ORDER, OB_START() DOESN'T WORK BEFORE WC_PRINT_NOTICES();
    wc_print_notices();
    ob_start();
?>

    <?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

    <div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

        <div class="u-column1 col-1">

    <?php endif; ?>

            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>
                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
                </p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

                <p class="form-row">
                    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                        <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                </p>
                <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                </p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

            </form>

    <?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

        </div>

        <div class="u-column2 col-2">

            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
                
                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide" id="company">
                    <label for="reg_company"><?php esc_html_e( 'Company', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="company" id="reg_company" autocomplete="company" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['company'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['company'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>
                
                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" autocomplete="given_name" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>
                
                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

                <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                    </p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

                <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                        <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                    </p>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row form-row">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                    <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                </p>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this **`woocommerce_process_registration_errors`** hook instead of `woocommerce_registration_errors`.

I have updated the code. **The parameters of the function are 4** and not 3 (if all are used).
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-form-handler.html#source-view.1078

> $validation_error  = apply_filters(
> 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', $validation_error,
> $username, $password, $email );

So the updated function will be:

```
// displays an error message if the first name and last name fields are empty
add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 'bbloomer_validate_woo_account_registration_fields', 10, 4 );
function bbloomer_validate_woo_account_registration_fields( $errors, $username, $password, $email ) {  
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.' );
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

It works for me. But I don't use shortcode but templates. In your case try to see here:

- [Display Woocommerce notices on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631939/display-woocommerce-notices-on-a-page)

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't see your answer. Thanks for the link. 
I tried it with this hook but it's the same result, there is no errror message.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check it out. You will need to insert an additional line in your shortcode.

Comment: I made the changes with 4 attr before, that was not the error. Then I tried your link and I accidently made it to show the error in the upper header where normally debug messages are shown. And there is a white paragraph added at the end of the page, probably because I do not ob_get_clean it.
I know, it's the wrong order (ob_start() should be before wc_print_notices();). If I add return ob_get_clean(); at the end of the form, the output again does not work.
Unfortunately, it's still not what I wanted, but better than nothing... I updated my code above.